# Value of normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

[image]

Can anyone tell me what will be the exact value of zα at a 95% confidence limit??
zα is the standardized normal variable with (1 − α) confidence level.
I am using this equation to find limits for Q-statistics. I am having doubt over only zα that whether it will be the p-value of normal distribution or something else??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some differences among sources, however a common meaning of $z_{\alpha}$ is the *$z$ value that the area under the PDF upto it is $1-\alpha$*, i.e. 
$$P(X\leq z_\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^{z_\alpha}\phi(x)dx=1-\alpha$$ 
where $\phi(x)$ denotes the standard normal PDF. You can find the value of an approximate $z_\alpha$ using *Z-tables* (e.g. [here](http://www.z-table.com/), or a quick search on the net).

Comment: Thanks for the help